# Move all files from one S3 location to another (same bucket) based on 'LastModified'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying replicate 2nd answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536720/move-s3-files-older-than-100-days-to-another-bucket)

**Issue:**

Need to move all files from location A to location B based on 'LastModified'. But the code on the original post is from bucket to bucket. I need to move it from a folder to another folder within the same bucket.

**Code:**

```
source_prefix = 'path_to_source/'
target_prefix = 'path_to_target/'

# create s3 client
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# create a reusable paginator
paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

# create a PageIterator from paginator
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=source_prefix)

# loop through each object, look for files older than 1 hr from current time 
for page in page_iterator:
    for object in page['Contents']:
        if object['LastModified'] < datetime.now().astimezone() - timedelta(hours=1):
            print(f"Moving {object['Key']}")
            
            # Copy object
            s3_client.copy_object(
                Bucket=bucket,
                Prefix=target_prefix,
                Key=object['Key'],
                CopySource={'Bucket':bucket, 'Prefix':source_prefix, 'Key':object['Key']}
             )
```

I added 'Prefix=target_prefix' to the copy object at the end.
But I am getting the following error:

botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "Prefix", must be one of:

**Question:**
How do I iterate through the objects and copy from one prefix location to another prefix location?

Comment: buckets don't have "folders", the name of the key can have / bars and that's enough. Just move the new file as "example/file.csv" and it will auto-create the "example" folder. So just edit the `Key` value of copy_object. I suggest f-strings for that concatenation.  `Key=f"{target_prefix}{object['Key']}"`. BONUS: Don't name `object` that var... it will give you issues in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boto3 [`copy_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) call does not accept a `Prefix` parameter.

The `Key` contains the full path of where to create the object. In fact, it becomes the Key of the new object (including the full path).

**I will assume your requirements are:** 'Move' objects from a source path to a target path (within the same bucket) if the object is older than one hour.

(Please note that there is not "move" command in S3 -- instead, it requires a Copy and a Delete.)

Here is some code that will do this:

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
INPUT_PATH = 'input/'
OUTPUT_PATH = 'output/'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# Create a reusable Paginator
paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

# Create a PageIterator from the Paginator
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=BUCKET,Prefix=INPUT_PATH)

# Loop through each object, looking for ones older than a given time period
for page in page_iterator:
    if 'Contents' in page:
        for object in page['Contents']:
            if object['LastModified'] < datetime.now().astimezone() - timedelta(hours=1):   # <-- Change time period here
                
                # Strip off input path and add output path
                source_key = object['Key']
                target_key = OUTPUT_PATH + source_key[len(INPUT_PATH):] 
                print(f"Moving {source_key} to {target_key}")

                # Copy object
                s3_client.copy_object(
                    Bucket=BUCKET,
                    Key=target_key,
                    CopySource={'Bucket':BUCKET, 'Key':source_key}
                )

                # Delete original object
                s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=source_key)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. One thing I noticed was that last line on this code (delete_object) deletes the whole "folder". Is there a way I can just get files in the "folder" deleted and leave the original folder? Would I need to use a for loop to iterate?

Comment: Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. For example, if you had an empty bucket and copied a file to `folder1/file.txt`, then `folder1` would magically appear. Then, if you delete the file, the folder will magically disappear. This is because the Key (filename) of an object is its full path, and folders are displayed merely as a convenience to humans. If you _really_ want an empty folder to appear, the S3 management console has a "Create Folder" button that will create a zero-length object with the same name as the folder. This will make the folder appear even when empty.